# jquery mobile checkbox not getting selected

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm displaying a list of items that user can select from.(multiple selection). My requirements are 1) if an item is selected, the whole row should be highlighted, not just the checkbox icon
eg)**http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html (Vertically grouped checkboxes**)
2) checkbox icon shouldn't be displayed

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/q6k9h/6/)
[Live version](http://haripriyaa.zymichost.com/ot/filter_03.html)

```
<div id="content" data-role="content">
        <div id="list-checkboxes" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical"data-theme="m">
                <label for="chb_1" data-theme="m" >Car</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chb_1" id="chb_1" class="custom" />
                <label for="chb_2">Van</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chb_2" id="chb_2" class="custom" />

            </fieldset>    
        </div><!-- /content -->
```

Comment: jQuery Mobile only supports data-type="horizontal" for checkboxes. You might have some luck with vertically grouped buttons by manipulating CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the css as follows to achieve this:

```
#verticalSelect .ui-checkbox{
   clear:both;
    /*float:none;*/

}

#verticalSelect .ui-checkbox .ui-btn{
   border-radius:0;
    border-top-width:0;

}

#verticalSelect .ui-checkbox:first-of-type .ui-btn{
   border-top-left-radius:0.6em;
    border-top-right-radius:0.6em;
    border-top-width:1px;

}

#verticalSelect .ui-checkbox:last-of-type .ui-btn{
   border-bottom-left-radius:0.6em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0.6em;
}
```

The idea is to remove the floating of each of the items and tweak the border styles.

Full demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/c59FN/